# Efficiently finding all pairs of disjoint sets

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Say we have the letters $\Omega = \{1,2,\dots n\}$, and two sets of subsets of $\Omega$, $S_1, S_2$.

I want to find $S_1 \cdot S_2 := \{(s_1,s_2) \in S_1 \times S_2: s_1 \cap s_2 = \emptyset \}$. With the sets I'm working with, the cardinality of $|S_1 \cdot S_2|$ should be considerably smaller than $|S_1||S_2|$, thus I was wondering if there's a better solution. Is there an efficient data structure, which after preptime, can generate $S_1 \cdot S_2$, in $O(|S_1 \cdot S_2|+n^c)$ time? (so it takes polynomial time to create to encodes the pairings, and then constant time to return each pairing) I'd imagine there'd be a smart way to do this with posets, but a concrete structure eludes me currently.

If so, is there a way to be able to quickly update our structure, allowing us to add supersets of elements like so:

$$S_1 = S_1 \cup \{f(s_1,s_2) \supset s_1, \forall (s_1,s_2) \in S_1 \cdot S_2 \}$$
$$ S_2 = S_2 \cup \{ g(s_1,s_2) \supset s_2, \forall (s_1,s_2) \in S_1 \cdot S_2\}$$

with complexity $O(n^c|S_1 \cdot S_2|)$, where $f$ and $g$ are some arbitrary functions with the stated superset properties?

Comment: Can you please clarify my doubt. $S_1 \times S_2$ is set whose elements are pairs of form $(i,j) \text{ such that } i\in S_1 \text{ and } j\in S_2$. Then how can we use $\cap$ to compare $i \text{ and } j$.

Comment: $S_1$ and $S_2$ both contain subsets of $\Omega$ as elements.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/39976/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109399/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75915/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70405/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11572/755

Comment: A useful keyword is "orthogonal vectors".